nfs hang issue, but telnet to nfs server is working
recently some of our servers have hanging issue, when I try "df" or "ls /data/mountA", the command is stuck. However when I was trying telnet to ntpserver with port 2049 and it is working.
The strang thing is "ls -l /data/mountA" is hanging on only some of our servers, but on others servers this command("ls -l /data/mountA" is working and return permission deny immediately) it is working. I wonder anyone have idea why this happened? and how to troubleshoot?

Please add more context, like server OS, client OS, nfs version number, mount options...
